# A cartridge is not detected as available for printing

Tags: printing, printer, inkjet-printer

I recently purchased an `HP Deskjet 1110` printer from Amazon for the personal usages. Its been one and half month since it arrive and I only tried it today for some test printing. The printer itself runs fine as well as the insertion and flow of the papers. However, I don't see any text printer with ink on the paper. I get the message from the printer:

> Single ink cartridge mode: Black. A cartridge is not detected as
>   available for printing. Although your printer can print in
>   single-cartridge mode (and your printer may have come with only one
>   cartridge), you may wish to add the missing cartridge to enhance print
>   performance and quality. Single cartridge mode printing may be slower
>   and printed colors may vary from those you would see with all
>   cartridges installed. If all cartridges are actually installed, check
>   that the plastic tape covering the ink nozzles has been removed so
>   that the printer can detect the cartridge. Alternatively, remove the
>   cartridge and re-insert it securely.

I tried to open it and re-inserted again, clean the connector inside with coffee filter etc but the issue persisted. What should I do now?

Comment: Do you only have a black cartridge? Are you printing colored text?

Comment: I have both cartridges came along the printer and I haven't printed a colored text. I think either the black cartridge is down or the printer connection is corrupted. It's expensive to buy a cartridge is Germany and maybe the second hand is a better option for me. I am thinking about what I should do in the situation.

Comment: Look in printer properties for useful settings.

Comment: I checked it but don't know what went wrong and WAT to check exactly. I have a Mac OS platform.